# Ограничение размера репозиториев в gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

```
GitLab information
Version:    7.14.3
Revision:   d321305
```

Возможно ли в данной версии gitlab установить ограничение для всех создаваемых и текущих репозиториев пользователей системы по занимаемому размеру на диске (квотирование)? Так же было бы неплохо уведомлять о приближении к установленному порогу либо о достижении оного (не важно как - хоть по email, хоть сообщением в панели самого gitlab). Соответственно, имеется ли данный функционал в более новых версиях?

Comment: *Возможно ли* — а в документации к программе не написано? если нет, значит, невозможно (средствами программы).

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Скажите, а разве в документации, на пример, к пылесосу написано, что им нельзя чистить котов? Вроде нет, но тем менее некоторые это практикуют (судя по встречающимся периодически видео в "интернетах")...

Comment: пожалуйста! ввиду того, что о сущствовании своих пользователях знает только программа gitlab, именно в ней и должна реализовываться подобная (насколько я понимаю, довольно ресурсоёмкая) функциональность. если таковая не описана в документации, она отсутствует.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если все станут **тщательно** изучать документацию, то на сайте  останутся вопросы только от людей, не способных ее понять. Вам захочется с ними общаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> имеется ли данный функционал в более новых версиях?

скоро появится. как только кто-нибудь реализует хотя бы: подсчёт, хранение и отображение необходимой информации. есть уже [14 желающих этим воспользоваться](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5627348-notify-admin-whenever-the-sum-of-size-of-repositor).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Будем ждать - очень нужная фича и как назло нет :(